# Is it safe to overwrite app config after 1st config assignment is made (and doesn't it negate the benefit of facotry pattern)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-unittest, python-config

Hello so we have couple of methods to setup app configurations in Flask.

1. `ENV` var directly in cmd before running flask
2. `app.config['xxx']`
3. `app.config.from_object` (module or class)
4. `app.config.from_pyfile` (file)
5. `app.config.from_envvar` (FILEPATH_ENVVAR)

I have read that for example when unit testing, it is best to implement factory pattern as some configs don't work when overwritten.

So I am wondering if it is safe to use multiple methods from above?

For example if i follow below steps together then is it safe to assume config will be applied correctly?

Step 1: Use method 1 before running application (for example to set `ENV` var secret key **or** to setup an `ENV` var that can be checked in the code at step 2 to decide whether to apply dev/prod config settings class **or** to set `ENV` var PATH_TO_SOMECONFIGFILE)

Step 2: Immediately after initializing the app object, use method 3 (to set default production settings **or** check `ENV` var set in above step to invoke appropriate dev/prod class).

Step 3: Immediately after above step, use method 4 or 5 to update the config settings

So will the settings from step 3 overwrite all previous (previously set) settings correctly? And is this good practice? And doesn't it negate the benefit of using factory pattern since I have read that not using factory pattern (for example while unit testing) could result in certain config if updated will not apply correctly. Hence create factory pattern to get fresh object with the needed config applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start by answering your questions and then I'll continue with a few explanations regarding configuration best practices.

> So I am wondering if it is safe to use multiple methods from above?

**Yes**. And it's in fact **recommended** that you use multiple ways of loading your configuration (see below why).

> So will the settings from step 3 overwrite all previous (previously
>   set) settings correctly? And is this good practice?

**Yes**. And usually the best way to learn things is to try things out. So I'll give you an example below, using classes and inheritance just to prove how overriding works (you can paste this in a Python module and run it, assuming you have Flask installed), but you should go ahead and experiment with all of the above methods that you've read about and mix and match them to solidify your knowledge.

```
from flask import Flask


class Config:
    LOGGING_CONFIGURATION = None
    DATABASE = None

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    LOGGING_CONFIGURATION = 'Development'
    DATABASE = 'development.db'

class TestConfig(Config):
    LOGGING_CONFIGURATION = 'Test'
    DATABASE = 'test.db'


def create_app(config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)  # we load the default configuration
    print(app.config['LOGGING_CONFIGURATION'], app.config['DATABASE'])
    app.config.from_object(config)  # we override with the parameter config
    print(app.config['LOGGING_CONFIGURATION'], app.config['DATABASE'])
    return app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app(DevelopmentConfig)
    test_app = create_app(TestConfig)  # you do this during tests
```

outputs

```
None None
Development development.db
None None
Test test.db
```

> And Doesn't it negate the benefit of using factory pattern since I
>   have read that not using factory pattern (for example while unit
>   testing) could result in certain config if updated will not apply
>   correctly. Hence create factory pattern to get fresh object with the
>   needed config applied.

**No**. You're confusing things here, loading configurations and using application factories are NOT mutually exclusive. In fact, they work together.

You are correct that messing with some config values, such as [ENV](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#ENV) and [DEBUG](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#DEBUG), which are special config values may cause the application to behave inconsistently. More details on those special vales [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#environment-and-debug-features). So try not to alter those once the application has finished setting up. See more in the **word of advice** section below.

---

### Further clarifications

The way Flask is designed usually requires the configuration to be available when the application starts up, and you usually need SOME KIND of configuration because, depending on your environment you might want to change different settings like:

- the [SECRET KEY](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/?highlight=from_pyfile#flask.Flask.secret_key) for example (if you're using Cookies for instance)
- toggle the [DEBUG mode](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#DEBUG) (you definitely don't want to use this in production, but you do in development mode)
- using a different [DATABASE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3) (which might be a path to a different file, if you're using SQLITE3, which is super useful in tests, where you don't want to use the production database)
- using a different [logging configuration](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig) (you'll maybe want critical information logged to a FILE in production, but in development you'll want everything logged to the CONSOLE, for debugging purposes)
- etc

Now you see that, because you need different settings for different configurations, you'll need **some kind of mechanism to toggle between configurations**, which is why using all those methods above **combined** is useful and recommended, because generally you'll load some kind of *DEFAULT* configuration, and override accordingly based on the environment (*PRODUCTION*, *DEVELOPMENT*, etc).

The way you would achieve all the above is described very meticulously with enough examples [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#configuration-handling), which is beyond the scope of this thread, but I'd encourage you to go through each example and try it out.

I also have an [open source app](https://github.com/mariusmucenicu/knowlift), built with Flask, where I've used classes and inheritance to load different configurations based on different environments and went even further to customise those as well. So not only do I load, say, the *DEVELOPMENT* configuration, but I even customise it further should I want to. Examples are [here](https://github.com/mariusmucenicu/knowlift/blob/master/default_settings.py), and I load them from [here](https://github.com/mariusmucenicu/knowlift/blob/master/knowlift/__init__.py). Do try to understand the mechanism by which I load the configuration, it will help you.

**Edit**:

The [config](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.config) object is just a subclass of a dictionary that has additional methods that help you load configurations from different places (the ones you've seen above):

- It doesn't matter how you load or override your configuration. All the settings will be loaded into the `config` dictionary. This belongs to the Flask object. This is where your configuration will live.
- So it doesn't matter whether you do:

```
  # override a setting if it exists or add it if it doesn't
  # just like you would do in a normal dictionary
  app.config[key] = value

  # this will either override all the values that are loaded
  # from that object or it will add them
  app.config.from_pyobject(object)

  # same as above, and the same goes for any method you use to add/override
  app.config.from_pyfile(filename)
```

The same goes for any other method not listed here that might load/override settings. They all have the same precedence, just be careful of the order in which you override, the configuration you load last is the one that the app will use.

---

### Word of advice

Try to load your configuration, along with all its core settings, regardless of your environment, as soon as your application starts up, and **don't alter them from that point forward**. If you find you are altering a lot of settings from different parts of the application, after the application is running (i.e you're doing a lot of `app[value] = another_value`), try to rethink your design, as that is an unstable implementation. What if a part of an application is expecting a setting that hasn't been set up by another part of the application ? Don't do that.

Comment: For the 2nd question - you have given example of inheritance. I am aware about this - my question of overwriting was to do with using app.config(.. for the 2nd time onward. Please can you clarify on that too.

Comment: @variable edited my answer... in short, regardless of whether you do `app.config[key] = value`, `app.config.from_object`, etc. they all do the same thing. The only difference is **HOW** they do it. My example used inheritance (I picked it randomly), which used `from_object`, but it would have been the same if I were to load the configuration from a file via `from_pyfile`, or to add each setting manually via `config[setting] = value`. The only thing that matters is the order in which these commands are executed (the last one overriding all the previous, for conflicting settings).

Comment: If we can overwrite config like this, then what is benefit of factory function - that is - initializing, configuring and returning the app object from factory function?

Comment: @variable factories are not mandatory, you can do perfectly fine without them. You could achieve the same behaviour using different configurations, and toggle between those configurations using `ENV` variables. You could also do the same thing with a factory, that takes in a `config_name` as its param, and load the desired config based on that param, and now you can toggle it via the command line when you run the app, or the tests. `export FLASK_APP="myapp:create_app('dev')"` and then do `flask run`. You can do fine without factories, but you cannot do fine without some sort of configuration.

Comment: They are, of course, also useful, in more advanced scenarios when you want to run different versions of the same application. See [this page](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/#application-factories) for use cases and examples.

Comment: This is out of topic, but out of curiosity - without factory method, we could use environment variable and based on its value write an if loop to load appropriate config file. Then what benefit does factory method exactly bring?